# A truncated exponential distribution is surely not an exponential distriution?

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, truncation

I'm currently working through a set of old past exam papers for a course, and came across this question which just has me flummoxed. I've slightly rephrased the relevant information and the question itself below, but am confident it's true to what's being asked:

- $X$ has an exponential distribution, with a mean of $1$.
- $Y = \begin{cases}
      X-2,& \text{if } X \geq 2\\
      0,              & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$
- Question - explain why the distribution of $Y$ is exponential with mean $1$.

This can't be so, right? Surely there's a point mass at $Y=0$?
The solution they give is  to prove the cumulative distributions match, as follows:

$$
P(Y \leq x) = P(X-2 \leq x | X > 2)=P(X \leq x+2 | X > 2)=P(X \leq x)
$$

This seems to go wrong in the second step. Shouldn't it be:
$$
\begin{align}
P(Y \leq x) &= P(X-2 \leq x | X \geq 2)P(X\geq 2) + P(X-2 \leq x | X < 2)P(X<2) \\
&= P(X-2 \leq x | X \geq 2)P(X\geq 2) + 1*P(X<2) \\
&= P(X \leq x+2 | X \geq 2)P(X\geq 2) + P(X<2) \\
&= P(X \leq x)P(X\geq 2) + P(X<2)
\end{align}
$$

which would indeed indicate a point mass at $0$?

Comment: Indeed, wrong question, $Y$ does have a point mass at zero.

Comment: The original question wouldn't have happened to say "... distribution of $Y$ given $Y > 0$", would it?  I can't make sense of it otherwise.

Comment: I don't have the original question to hand right now, but I went through it  a number of times trying to find anywhere they specified this or a similar condition and came up with nothing. I guess they've left something out somewhere in it.

Answer (score 2):

That statement provided clearly is not correct, as @Xi'an pointed out. It could be fixed up to be like the following:

Define a shifted, truncated exponential distribution function such that the probability density function such that

$f_Y(y) \propto \begin{cases}
          f_X(y + 2) & \text{if } y \ge 0\\
          0          & \text{otherwise}
          \end{cases}$

Where $f_X$ is the density function of an exponential distribution of mean 1. Then $Y$ will, in fact, follow an exponential distribution with mean 1. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Note that this is like shifting and truncating; if $A = B + 1$ for random variables $A$ and $B$, then $f_A(a) = f_B(a - 1)$, and we then truncated $Y$ so that it will be non-negative, which involves setting $f_Y(y)$ to 0 for $y < 0$ and then restandardizing so that $f_Y$ integrates to 1.